# How many odd permutation of order 4 does $S_{6}$ have?

Tags: group-theory

> Question: How many odd permutation of order 4 does $S_{6}$ have?

Possibly,

there is 1 cycle of length 6-odd

1 cycle of length 4 and 1 cycle of length 2-even

2 cycle of length 3-odd

3 cycle of length 2-even

Now $S_{6}$ have order 6!=720
By the alternating group definition, 360 permutations are odd and another 360 permutations are even.

Looking at the above, the odd permutation does not have order 4.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A $4$-cycle is odd.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes. A 4-cycle is an odd permutation. A 2-cycle if odd too.
Then, isn't the product of two odd permutation even?

Comment: Why is that relevant? I gave you an example of an odd permutation of order $4$.

Comment: Of the $720$ permutations in $S_6,$ only $265$ of them have no fixed points (such permutations are called derangements), and they are the only ones you considered. The other $455$ elements of $S_6$ have one or more fixed points ($1$-cycles) and among them you will find some odd permutations of order $4.$ One of them is $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)(5)(6).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of a permutation is the least common multiple of its cycle lengths. If the order is $4$, all cycle lengths must be $1$, $2$ or $4$, and at least one must be $4$. The cycle lengths must add up to $6$. That leaves the two options $4,2$ and $4,1,1$. The first is even and the second odd, so the only odd permutations of order $4$ in $S_6$ are the $4$-cycles. These can be counted by choosing the two fixed points in $\binom62$ ways and choosing one of $3!$ cyclically inequivalent orders in the $4$-cycle, for a total of $\binom62\cdot3!=90$.

Comment: A fine explanation indeed. I now see where my thought process when wrong. Thanks!